# Can Chuppah have a fixed roof?

Tags: halacha, wedding, chupah

There are many approaches to a [Chuppah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chuppah) and I only refer to our Ashkenazi tradition of 4 bars/hands and a canopy. I saw that many wedding halls have a fixed cube-like construction, but the covering is always a cloth.

Can the whole Chuppah be made of wood or stone Halachicly? If not Halachic, is there any Kabbalic explanation to this tradition?

Answer (score 1):

Rema EH 55.1

> הגה: ויש אומרים דחופה אינו יחוד, אלא כל שהביאה החתן לביתו לשם נשואין (כן כתב הר"ן בשם יש אומרים ריש כתובות). ויש אומרים שהחופה היא שפורסין סודר על ראשה בשעת הברכה (הבית יוסף הביאו). ויש אומרים דחופת בתולה משיצאה בהינומא; ואלמנה, משנתיחדו (תוספות פרק קמא דיומא). והמנהג פשוט עכשיו לקרות חופה מקום שמכניסים שם יריעה פרוסה על גבי כלונסות, ומכניסים תחתיה החתן והכלה ברבים, ומקדשה שם ומברכין שם ברכת ארוסין ונשואין, ואחר כך מוליכים אותם לביתם ואוכלים ביחד במקום צנוע, וזהו החופה הנוהגת עכשיו. ועיין לקמן סימן ס"ב סעיף ט' וסימן ס"א:‏

He mentions klunsaot, stakes. This name doesn't imply not fixed stakes. Canopy is a minimum. It is used when the stakes are not fixed.

Comment: He mentions "יריעה פרוסה" as a Minhag, but gives no reason for that, so I ask whether a fixed roof can work also.